# Is there a matrix product which results in this relation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Let $\pmb{a} = \left[a_1\;a_2\;\dots\;a_n\right], \pmb{b} = \left[b_1\;b_2\;\dots\;b_m\right]$. Then 
$$K = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a_1b_1 & a_1b_2 & \cdots & a_1b_m \\
a_2b_1 & a_2b_2 & \cdots & a_2b_m\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_nb_1 & a_nb_2& \cdots& a_nb_m\end{array} \right)$$
is a matrix formed by some sort of product. Is there some way, $\otimes$, to relate these two vectors to $K$? In other words does there exist some operation such that $\pmb{a} \oplus \pmb{b} = K$, or maybe under arbitrary transpositions of $\pmb{a}$ or $\pmb{b}$ there exists a $\otimes$ such that $K$ is the result?

Thanks!

Comment: $\mathbf{a}^\top\mathbf{b}$ is what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the outer product $a b^{T}$ for a,b as column vectors.